# Maven2 + JMeter + JUnit with dependencies

Tags: maven-2, junit, jmeter

I'd like to run my JUnit tests in JMeter. Using maven-jar-plugin I can create a jar with my tests in order to put it inside the JMeter's classpath ($JMETER_HOME/lib/junit). The problem is that my tests have a lot of dependencies that Maven2 doesn't put into the jar, including the main classes of the project, classes from other projects and external libraries. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [fatjar plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-fatjar-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

As iwein has mentioned, you may use the [maven-fatjar-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-fatjar-plugin/) which will put all the dependent JAR's inside of your JAR artifact and create the appropriate MANIFEST entries to include them on your classpath.

Another option is that you can use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) which will simply take all of the ".class" files out of the dependecy JARs and include them directly in your JAR. This is called a UBER-JAR. There are a couple of reasons which I prefer this approach:

1. This often leads to slightly smaller JARs
2. I have other plugins which already manipulate the MANIFEST (including the Classpath property) and I don't want to chance having an incorrect manifest being generated.
3. Creating an UBER-JAR is just too good to pass up ;)